# How to address Invoice from freelancer to a company

Tags: salary, company-policy, freelancing, invoices

I am a freelancer working for a company. I need to send an invoice to them in order to get paid. I am not a company and so I will just write my name, address, mobile and email for my details.
For the customer’s (company) details, I see on templates online to write name, company, address, mobile and email.

What I don’t understand is whether I should write a name at all in the company details since I am employed by the company and not a person. Also, if I do write a name (perhaps who I send my invoice to), should the details of address, mobile and email be their company details or the general details of the company?

Comment: You should ask them exactly what details they want.

Comment: We cannot answer this. In case your company contracts other freelancers, there is pretty good chance that they can help you with a template for invoicing. so, just ask.

Comment: This question is receiving close votes because you're asking questions to an online audience that cannot answer them, as these are things to ask the company in question. And several of the guides on sending invoices I've found mention to use the name of the contact or just the company itself. So more research would have likely helped you. Now, people who are new to freelancing might not be familiar with some of this nor do we exclude questions for being "too simple" but I'm afraid that's probably what lead to the negative reception your question received here.

Comment: "What I don’t understand is whether I should write a name at all in the company details since I am employed by the company and not a person. "  I'm confused by this - the invoice should be addressed to the company who hired you; it should be from your company if you are a legal entity or your own name if not (Joe Bloggs trading as Joe Bloggs Consulting may be ok for an unincorporated business depending on your jurisdiction).

Answer (score 2):

These are the questions you can ask your client. Always ask the client, not the internet.

"Who should I address my invoices to?"

"Who should I send my invoices to?"

"Do you prefer they be emailed or sent via postal mail?"

"What level of detail should I provide in my invoice? Do you have specific requirements?"

Answer (score -1):

yes, you should send an invoice once you completed the task.
the invoice helps the company with tax-related problems.

your invoice should have

1. Title
2. Name and logo of the company
3. Address and contact info
4. client name and other information
5. date & invoice number
6. tasks you have done.
7. the amount or due amount
8. signature

Or contact the particular person or company about the format.